# How to partially disable resize properties of NSWindow?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

[image]

In one of my NSWindow (shown in above image) I want to disable split window properties i.e. "Tile Window to Left of Screen" & "Tile Window to Right of Screen".

My existing Window Controller code is provide below:

```
class VideoWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

        self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
        self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.init(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.window?.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.titled.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.closable.rawValue |  NSWindow.StyleMask.miniaturizable.rawValue)            
    }

    @objc func setNonResizableStyle() {
        self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
        self.window?.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: NSWindow.StyleMask.titled.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.miniaturizable.rawValue)
        self.window?.level = .floating
    }

    @objc func setResizableStyle() {
        self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
           self.window?.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.titled.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.closable.rawValue |  NSWindow.StyleMask.miniaturizable.rawValue)
        self.window?.level = .normal

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the `collectionBehavior` of your `NSWindow` object to disable certain split window features:

```
window?.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenDisallowsTiling]
```

More info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior